# dynamic store in column grid editable

Tags: extjs, grid, store

In a grid column editable (**ExtJs v4.2.2**), how to change the store dynamically ?
The point is to load store with different params by type of movement(movementTypeId):

the field with diffrent list to be attached is 'Reason', columns are:

```
this.columns = [
{
    text: 'id',
    dataIndex: 'movementId',
    sortable: false,
    hideable: true,
    sortableColumn: false,
    hidden: true,
    flex : 1,
    scope:this
},
{
    text: 'TypeId',
    dataIndex: 'movementTypeId',
    sortable: false,
    sortableColumn: false,
    hideable: true,
    sortableColumns: false,
    hidden: true,
    flex : 2,
    scope:this
},

{
    text: 'Reason',
    dataIndex: 'movementReasonId',
    sortable: false,
    hideable: true,
    sortableColumn: false,
    field: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        align: 'center',
        typeAhead: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        //selectOnTab: true,
        store: this.storeMovementReasonType,
        displayField: 'label'
    },
    flex : 3,
    scope:this
},

];
```

So for every row, when store is on load wanted to set extra param like:

```
if(movementTypeId === 89){
 storeMovementReasonType.getProxy().setExtraParam('dictionaryTypeId',11);
 }
 if(movementTypeId === 94){
    storeMovementReasonType.getProxy().setExtraParam('dictionaryTypeId',8);
 }
```

is it possible ?
Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to implement the [`beforeedit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing.html#event-beforeedit) listener on your rowediting plugin:

```
listeners:{
    beforeedit:function(editor , context , eOpts) {
        var movementTypeId = context.record.get("movementTypeId");
        if(movementTypeId === 89){
            storeMovementReasonType.getProxy().setExtraParam('dictionaryTypeId',11);
        }
        if(movementTypeId === 94){
            storeMovementReasonType.getProxy().setExtraParam('dictionaryTypeId',8);
        }
        storeMovementReasonType.load();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to display the field Value of the store on the grid too. I'm using renderer, and wait for the store loaded before returning label, but the renderer method does't wait for the return.. do you have an idea ?

Comment: @aurny2420289 Hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet.